# How can I use SELECT statement into UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have this *TRIGGER* which is `AFTER INSERT`:

```
BEGIN
IF new.score IS NOT NULL THEN

INSERT INTO reputations(event_table_id, type, score, question_id, post_id, table_code, comment_id, owner_id, date_time)
SELECT new.id, new.type, new.score, t1.id, new.post_id, new.table_code, new.comment_id, new.author_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
FROM qanda t1 
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM qanda t2 
               WHERE ID = new.post_id 
                 AND t1.ID = t2.related)
           or t1.id = new.post_id)
  AND Type = 0;

END IF;
END
```

Now I want to do the same thing also `AFTER UPDATE`. How can I do that?

Here is what I've tried:

```
BEGIN 

IF new.score IS NOT NULL THEN

UPDATE reputations SET type = new.type,
                       score = new.score,
                       question_id = <I don't know>,
                       post_id = new.post_id,
                       table_code = new.table_code,
                       comment_id = new.comment_id,
                       owner_id = new.author_id,
                       date_time = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE event_table_id = old.id

END IF;
END
```

Does anybody know what should I write instead of `<I don't know>` part?

Comment: Try surrounding your SELECT statement with parenthesis: question_id = (SELECT x FROM y WHERE ...), It must return one value only, or It will throw an error